# Method for deriving an Exponential Moving Average?

Tags: calculus, statistics, derivatives, recurrence-relations, time-series

I have a formula for an exponentially weighted moving average function defined recursively as:

$S_t = a*Y_t+(1-a)*S_{t-1}$

Where:

- $a\in (0,1)\cap \mathbb{Q}$
- $t$ represents time
- $Y_t$ is the value at a time period $t$
- $S_t$ is the value of the EMA at any time period t.

I am trying to find a generally applicable solution for the derivative of $S_t$ in regards to $dt$.

Any assistance would be most appreciated!

Comment: The parenthesis in the last expression seems a bit funny...

Comment: I didn't notice that, fixed it now.

Comment: Hint: 

$$ aY_t + (1 - a)S_{t - 1} = aY_t + (1 - a)(aY_{t-1} + (1 - a)S_{t-2}) = \sum_{k=0}^{i-1}{a(1 - a)^kY_{t-k}} +(1-a)^iS_{t-i}$$

Although, I'm not sure what to make of $S_0$ or $Y_i$ without some more information.

Comment: @ChantryCargill What sort of information do you require? Also, am I correct in interpreting that $*i*$ represents the initial time and k represents the current time? If it helps, the original formula is the formula for an exponential moving average. $$t\in (1,\infty)\cap \mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: Maybe I'm misinterpreting the question, but what is $Y_t$. How is it defined?

Comment: @ChantryCargill $Y_t$ is a value at a time period t. Y is a set of values. E.g. When Y=1 t=1, Y=7 t=2, Y=49 t=3, etc. The values of Y do not necessarily have any pattern to them and can consist of any values.